# Checkstyle plugin in Eclipse: Checkstyle Execution failed due to an internal error

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue.
I have Eclipse Ide for enterprise java and web developers installed, version 2021-06 (4.20.0) and Checkstyle plugin, version 8.44.0.

Edit: my SO is ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

The problem is when I create a new configuration, either from scratch or copying Suns Check configuration (that is my goal, I want a configuration like Suns check but with some differences) from the menu Window -> preferences -> Checkstyle.
Then, after I create the configuration, I try to use it on a project (a standard java project) by right-clicking the project, properties and go to checkstyle, select "checkstyle active for this project" and then select the configuration I just created from the dropdown. And after that, right-clicking the project, going to checkstyle -> "check code with checkstyle" results in the folliwing message:

> Checkstyle Execution failed due to an internal error, please check the error log for details...

So I did, I went to the eclipse log, and found the following:

```
> 
!ENTRY net.sf.eclipsecs.core 4 0 2021-10-22 23:19:43.102
!MESSAGE Checkstyle-Plugin: unable to parse configuration stream
!STACK 0
com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: unable to parse configuration stream
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:325)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:287)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckerFactory.createCheckerInternal(CheckerFactory.java:217)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckerFactory.createChecker(CheckerFactory.java:122)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.Auditor.runAudit(Auditor.java:139)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckstyleBuilder.handleBuildSelection(CheckstyleBuilder.java:307)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.jobs.RunCheckstyleOnFilesJob.runInWorkspace(RunCheckstyleOnFilesJob.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Property ${org.checkstyle.sun.suppressionxpathfilter.config} has not been set
com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Property ${org.checkstyle.sun.suppressionxpathfilter.config} has not been set
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader$InternalLoader.startElement(ConfigurationLoader.java:530)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:752)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1386)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2725)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.XmlLoader.parseInputSource(XmlLoader.java:86)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.parseInputSource(ConfigurationLoader.java:198)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:315)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Property ${org.checkstyle.sun.suppressionxpathfilter.config} has not been set
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.replaceProperties(ConfigurationLoader.java:376)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.access$500(ConfigurationLoader.java:51)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader$InternalLoader.startElement(ConfigurationLoader.java:525)

... 23 more
```

It seems to be a problem with the org.checkstyle.sun.suppressionxpathfilter.config property, so I googled it and found the following page:
https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/sun_style.html that says something about the default value this property should have, so I configured this value in the properties window for my configuration, but nothing changed.

What can be the cause of this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which Checkstyle plugin (there is more than one)? Please make sure Eclipse and the installed plugins are up to date and update your question accordingly.